# Kali Linux Freezing every time I load

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot

I just recently bought a chill blast PC and I'm trying to dual boot with windows & kail. I've used a 16gb San disk USB and Rufus to make a DD image and have booted t[Image][1]he  PC of from their. I have then installed it on my D drive in a space of 80gb. I have put everything their (home, etc) and installed it. All working fine, I haven't used network mirror and I have not connected it to the network. It installs and reboots, now, when I click "Kail linux x64" from the kail boot menu it just comes [Image][2]like this - (see attached). My windows 10 works fine booting that up. I have tried to boot also from recovery mode but that produces the same thing.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no images attached ...

Comment: Kali is absolutely not for beginners. Start on a more complete unix, switch to kali when you already know what you're doing. Compulsory kali link - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)